# React how to clear input and fire onChange event

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating react component library with own basic components and some logic on the top of that. I have wrapped classic input field with clearable button. I need implement **_onClearInput**, but idk how to fire onChange event with empty string value. Is there anyone who is able to help me?

```
import React, { ComponentPropsWithoutRef, useState } from 'react';

export interface MyInputProps extends ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'> {
}

const MyInput = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, MyInputProps>(({
    value,
    onChange,
    ...rest
}, ref) => {

    const [_value, _setValue] = useState(value || '');

    const _onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        _setValue(event.target.value);
        if(onChange) {
            onChange(event);
        }
    }

    const _onClearInput = () => {
        _setValue('');
        // I need trigger onChange event somehow with event.target.value = ''
    }

    return(
        <div className={`input-${_value === '' ? 'is-not' : 'is'}-set`}>
            <input ref={ref} value={_value} onChange={_onChange} {...rest}/>
            <button onClick={_onClearInput}>ClearInput</button>
        </div>
    );
});

export default MyInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any non-hackish way to do that if you want that the event have all required props, but as long as only the value is retrieved from the event, you can do that easily with:

```
if (onChange) {
    onChange({ target: { value: '' } });
}
```

Or with typescript:

```
if (onChange) {
    onChange({ target: { value: '' } } as React.ChangeEvent<
        HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement
    >);
}
```